# mongodb issue in java with limit and sort

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

Collection:progs

```
{ "_id" : "ABC", "defaultDirectory" : "abc", "defaultRecvDirectory" : "abc" }
{ "_id" : "RAS", "defaultRecvDirectory" : "recv/ras" }
{ "_id" : "SND", "defaultSendDirectory" : "send/snd" }
```

In the mongo console:

```
db.progs.find({"_id":{"$lt":"ZZZZZZZZZ"}}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1);

==>    { "_id" : "SND", "defaultSendDirectory" : "send/snd" }
```

In Java:

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", new BasicDBObject("$lt", "ZZZZZZZZZZ"));
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("_id","-1")).limit(1);
    for (DBObject dbObject : cursor) {
        System.out.println(dbObject);
    }

==>    { "_id" : "ABC", "defaultSendDirectory" : "abc", "defaultRecvDirectory" : "abc" }
```

Someone can explain the difference?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the `"-1"` in your sort:

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("_id",-1)).limit(1);
```

Or use Mongodb ASC/DESC constants from `com.mongodb.operation.OrderBy` instead of hardcoding 1 / -1

Example:

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject("_id", OrderBy.DESC.getIntRepresentation())).limit(1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another version based on MongoTemplate:

```
public List<?> findLimitedSorted(Query query, Object target, String startFrom) {
    query.limit(100);
    query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "<field_name>"));
    return getMongoTemplate().find(query, target.getClass());
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Always sort in your query, not after!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I found with filters, sorting and limit :

```
 List<Bson> queryFilters = new ArrayList<>();
    queryFilters.add(Filters.eq(SavedReportEntity.FIELD_USER_ID, userId));

   List<Document> documents = getMongoCollection().find(searchFilter).sort(sort).limit(10).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

you will get the list of Documents now you can play with it according to you.

Answer (score 0):

Getting DBObjects with sortting order from MongoDB:

```
List<DBObject> list = new LinkedList<DBObject>();    
    DBCursor cursor = db.getCollection("myCol").find().sort(new BasicDBObject("_id",-1)).limit(collection.find(query).count());
        while(cursur.hasNext){
        list.add(cursur.next());
    }
    if(!list.isEmpty())
        for(DBObject dbo: list){
            System.out.println(dbo);
        }
    else
        System.out.println("List is empty");
```

Comment: it would be nice if you add some explanation

Comment: Ma che cazzo è?